# Nested Internal Class with Readonly Hashtable throws Null ref exception.. on assignment

Tags: c#, design-patterns, compiler-errors, hashtable, nullreferenceexception

In my `internal Game class`, I have both a) defined another nested `internal GamerTags class` and b) defined a `GamerTags[] _array` variable.

In my `internal GamerTags class` *(the nested class, for simplicity I left it out)* I have a `readonly Hashtable`. After initialization, I still get a `null ref exception` when I try to assign a value. *I'm not changing the pointer but the value only*, do I need to add another initialization for the Hastable?

```
internal class GamerTags
    {
        private readonly Hashtable _privateReadonlyHashTable;
        private string _json;
        private string _hash;

        internal IDictionary privateReadonlyHashTable
        {
            get
            {
                return this._privateReadonlyHashTable;
            }
        }

        internal string Hash
        {
            get
            {
                this.EnsureHash();
                return this._hash;
            }
        }           

        internal object this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                return this._privateReadonlyHashTable[key];
            }
            set //throws an exception
            {
                this._privateReadonlyHashTable[key] = value;
            }
        }

        internal string Json
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._json))
                {
                    this._json = myJsonSerializer.Serialize(this._privateReadonlyHashTable);
                }
                return this._json;
            }
        }

        internal int X
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        internal int Y
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        internal GamerTags(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        private void EnsureHash()
        {
            bool flag = false;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._hash))
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    if (this.Json.Length < 100)
                    {
                        this._hash = this.Json;
                        return;
                    }
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.Json);
                    byte[] numArray = (new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()).ComputeHash(bytes);
                    this._hash = Convert.ToBase64String(numArray);
                    return;
                }
                this._hash = this.FastHash();
            }
        }

        private string FastHash()
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string key in this._privateReadonlyHashTable.Keys)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(key);
                stringBuilder.Append("_");
                stringBuilder.Append(this._privateReadonlyHashTable[key]);
                stringBuilder.Append("_");
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Init and assignment

```
        int a = 2; int b = 0;
        GamerTags GamerTag = new Game.GamerTags(a, b);
        GamerTag["Fuel"] = "Loaded";              //throws an exception
        GamerTag["EngineStatus"] = (boolIsItOn ? 1 : 0); //throw an exception too
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you need to instantiate the _privateReadonlyHashTable field.

```
internal class GamerTags
{
    private readonly Hashtable _privateReadonlyHashTable =  new Hashtable();

    ..
    ..
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, since this a nested internal class inside `Game class` I was hoping to get a _good design practice_. Also, multiple places seem to need to initialize/access hash the fly, I was wondering whether this was good practice or *there was an advantage* to initialize here in the class var declaration rather than from outside. If the container size and contents can change later as items are added/del, I'm guessing this might be the right place to do it, would that assumption be correct... can you share some more based on the usage from outside classes please

Comment: I'm not sure I've exactly got your intention but information hiding and encapsulation say hide information as much as possible. So if is is the matter of choosing between initializing from inside or outside the class when you just need add/del operations, I say inside so you expose an Indexer and Add/Del methods only instead of a whole HashTable. Besides, avoiding to expose the hashtable gives the inner class complete control over it and items that is added/removed to it. But your question is too general to answer accuratly.

Comment: encapsulation clearly is a benefit here, but the nature of `Readonly Hashtable _privateReadonlyHashTable` is making me unsure. 1) `Can outside actors pass a Hashtable` to me to initialize or 2) or if I got a `preinitialized Hashtable`, can the internal methods still manipulate the  `_privateReadonlyHashTable`. I'm wondering if there a safeway to do deferred initialization

Comment: 1) Outside actors can pass an HashTable through constructor.  2) If by manipulating, you mean accessing it's methods, yes, if you mean assigning another instance of HashTable to the _privateReadonlyHashTable field, no. I don't get what you mean by "safeway".

Comment: 1) is clear, 2) So, how can I address the scenario where someone may pass an outside Hashtable, and I would like to initialize it to the same, would this even be practical or recommended? _I do this often in nested objects in C++, not sure its good practice here_

Comment: There is no problem with receiving an instance of HashTable or any list from outside and working with that, unless you need full control over that list (e.g when you don't want the list gets modified by the client). Maybe another option in this case is cloning the passed HashTable in constructor so you have client provided items and also full control over the list. HashTable itself has an [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdkta2sx(v=vs.110).aspx) like that, receiving an IDictionary and copying it's elements. So you can use it to create your own clone in Constructor.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the class GametTags with

```
 GamerTags GamerTag = new Game.GamerTags(a, b);
```

no code seems to initialize the internal HashTable `_privateReadonlyHashTable`

A simple fix would be to initialize the `HashTable` at the same moment of the declaration

```
internal class GamerTags
{
    private readonly Hashtable _privateReadonlyHashTable = new HashTable();

    .....
    internal GamerTags(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    ......
}
```

Given the fact that your internal Hashtable is marked with the readonly modifier you have only another option to initialize it, and this is inside a constructor of your class like

```
internal class GamerTags
{
    private readonly Hashtable _privateReadonlyHashTable;

    .....
    internal GamerTags(int x, int y)
    {
        _privateReadonlyHashTable = new HashTable();
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    .....
}
```

but I prefer the first approach because, if you add a new constructor, then you should remember to put the initialization of the Hashtable also in the new constructor and if you forget to do it then you introduce a subtle bug that could be difficult to spot.

Comment: _after your init with `Readonly` will it continue to be dynamic size/items and support addition and deletion as a container?_.  If this was C++ I understand it would fix the base address, not the size. So, 1) I'm just not sure I understand how Readonly translates to Hashtable. 2) I have to think about this because its used inside another nested class that could/may need to initialize it. I guess 3)  I am asking *if initializing here is preferred & would eliminate all needs to initialize elsewhere*, and would this be good design to centralize it here.